# how to use jquery live() to add attribute to element

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a select element that is in the DOM from page load. Lets say it has an id of my_select like so:

```
<select name="my_select" id="my_select">
</select>
```

At some point though when the user does something some values are pulled in via ajax to populate this select element so that it now contains options. So it will now look like this:

```
<select name="my_select" id="my_select">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

So how do I then add an attribute to one of these options?

I want to do this:

```
$('#my_select option[value="2"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

But I think I need to use live() because the options were added via ajax after the DOM had been created.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an event that adds the attribute? like Click for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").delegate('#my_select", 'YOUREVENT', function(){
    $("#my_select option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the selected option can be done like this: `$('#my_select').val(2);` Are you looking for more?

Answer (score 0):

$.live is the same as $.bind, for event binding, the diference is "live" works for elements than not exists yet, and will be created by DOM scripting (i.e. ajax response).

the right form to set val = 2 is $('#my_select').val(2), when it's already in the dom ;)